# How can I find the memory size of a string

Tags: java, string, memory

I need to check if the size of a string is less than 1MB for the Binder transaction buffer which has a limit of 1MB.
Also the string may be UTF-16 encoded.

I found these 2 methods but I don't know if they are good.

- [minimum memory usage of a Java String](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml?fbclid=IwAR0F6eJKRrk2ZlPvqwogd6Ou9KAC4aBT-oKp7vN7dXDr6-tLT4G4gfj9F6Q) which uses the following:
  (bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)
- or using .getBytes().length (but I don't know what happens if UTF-16 chars appear)

Comment: The internal size of the string isn't supposed to matter - you need it for a buffer, so you'll be copying the data to the buffer. You are not going to allocate a Java string in your buffer, as that is impossible. Also note that you should use `.getBytes(...)` with a specific encoding, not leave it to the system default.

Answer (score -1):

You may use .getBytes().length but to avoid the problem of UTF-16 chars then use getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length

Comment: What is "the problem of UTF-16 chars"? Having UTF-8 encoding is potentially more problematic as it has a varying length encoding. UTF-16 is fixed and not problematic at all

Comment: I'm just as confused as you are